# How to create email pickup directory automatically?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

There is an email pickup directory in ASP.NET MVC application:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="no-reply@test.com" deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:/emails"/>
        <network host="localhost"/>
      </smtp>
   </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

The web app does not create the directory `c:\emails` automatically on startup. It is possible to set it up easily? Or do I need to parse web.config and create the directory on startup "manually"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's anything "out of the box" to do this - but to do this yourself is pretty easy, too.

You can use this snippet of code, and you could place this into e.g. your `global.asax.cs` file in one of the appropriate methods (e.g. `Application_Start`):

```
// get the config section <system.net>/<mailSettings>/<smtp>
SmtpSection smtpConfig = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp") as SmtpSection;

if (smtpConfig != null)
{
    // if you have DeliveryMethod=SpecifiedPickupDirectory
    if(smtpConfig.DeliveryMethod == SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory)
    {
        // read out the configured directory 
        string pickupDir = smtpConfig.SpecifiedPickupDirectory.PickupDirectoryLocation;

        // check if directory exists....
        if (!Directory.Exists(pickupDir))
        {
            // and if not - just create it!
            Directory.CreateDirectory(pickupDir);
        }
    }
}
```